# How to get all google reviews using business api

Tags: javascript, php, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

I need all google reviews for particular location but I am unable to use business api from google. Here is url for get request

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/account_name/locations/location_name/reviews
```

Now my question is what is the value for param account_name and location_name
How can I get that.

Please answer with sample location example

Comment: [API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v3/accounts.locations#resource-location) says it's based on the JSON's name field.  Scroll down to see `Google identifier for this location in the form: accounts/{account_id}/locations/{location_id}`

Answer (score 9):

I think first of all you need to white list your google my business api for whatever project you are working on in your project as its private api. Google my business api will work on the locations associated with your account so make sure you verified the LOCATIONS from any account you know. Then you can try out the api call you mentioned in OAuthplayground.

1. Follow steps mentioned in below documentation URL to set it up:
   https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs

After the setup and etc you will automatically understand the account id and location id.

Also few more urls you can go to understand it better.

2. https://console.developers.google.com (here you will setup your project)
3. https://business.google.com/manage (here you will add/can see the locations - for which you need reviews)
4. https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup (Steps after completing the prereq)
5. https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground (You will test the my
   business api here after approval)

Answer (score 5):

When you make a request to `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts` it gives you a list of accounts.  On those accounts they have a field called name.  That field is accounts/account_name.

```
{
  "state": {
    "status": "UNVERIFIED"
  }, 
  "type": "PERSONAL", 
  "name": "accounts/1337", 
  "accountName": "example"
}
```

When you make a request to `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/account_name/locations` it gives you a list of locations.  On those locations they have a field called name.  That field is accounts/account_name/locations/location_name.

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "languageCode": "en", 
      "openInfo": {
        "status": "OPEN", 
        "canReopen": true
      }, 
      "name": "accounts/1337/locations/13161337", 
      ...
}
```

Comment: While you'll have to update the domain to be the new api, the explanations to help people understand the usage remains the same.  The only change is that you use https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1 instead of https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3